# alsa, snd_pcm_drain(handle), the stream isn't played to the end

Tags: linux, alsa

Can someone explain how to safely stop from playing with ALSA drivers?
I use snd_pcm_writei() for write into ALSA ring buffer in chunks of "period" buffer sizes, pretty much simple. After write, I found it's difficult to safely exit, in terms of need to exit after all samples are played from ring buffer (inside driver).

After playing, I found that stream is still in SND_PCM_STATE_RUNNING state (enum 3) which seems normal, since rest of ring buffer needs to be played. So I tried pooling the state

```
do
{
    err = snd_pcm_state(handle);
}while(err==3);

printf("\nDone.\n\n"); // never gets here
```

Ok, there is a function for draining audio stream:

```
snd_pcm_drain(handle);
    do
    {
        err = snd_pcm_state(handle);
    }while(err==3);

    printf("\nDone.\n\n");
```

This ends up with code 1 which means SND_PCM_STATE_SETUP shoudn't ne STOP or something ?
But anyway, the stream isn't played until end. The only way to test is to put a

```
while(1);
```

And this ensures the whole audio is played. Any thoughts?

Thanks very much in advance,

I discovered the problem but need assistance to solve:

The function snd_pcm_writei() needs a const void* buffer and I use a dynamically allocated one:

```
snd_pcm_sframes_t snd_pcm_writei    (   snd_pcm_t *     pcm,
        const void *    buffer,
        snd_pcm_uframes_t   size 
    ) 

frames = snd_pcm_writei (handle, buff, period_size);

static short buf[240]; // this works

// this is not working
if ((buff = calloc(0,period_size)) == NULL) {
        printf("No enough memory for period buffer\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Any idea about how to use snd_pcm_writei() with a dynamically allocated buffer?

Answer (score 0):

To wait for the buffer to be played, `snd_pcm_drain` must be called in blocking mode, i.e., call `snd_pcm_nonblock(handle, 0)` before.

Setting one parameter of `calloc` to zero will allocate zero bytes.
To allocate a buffer that can hold the sample data of one period, use `calloc(period_size, frame_size)`.